# Microservices to microservices communication securely

Tags: java, spring, jwt, microservices, communication

I wants to communicate between different microservices, but the problem that is arising is microservices are secured with jwt token and I am not able to find a way to send a secured call to the other microservice from first microservice. Is there is a way I can communicate with the service method directly because if I make my api open it will be misused.

Or I have to go through api gateway to send every request through api gate way and make a secure communication from there.

Comment: Why not just pass the token trough to your other MS? Each MS could then verify again against the same token and you would only need to submit it on the initial API call.

Comment: My question would be why you need to communicate cross service in the first place? If it is purely to return data back to a caller than a gateway API would be the way to go. In my personal opinion Microservices should not have a need to talk to each other directly, though they might care about events triggered from one-another.

Comment: my requirement will be to get particular role from role ms to user ms, but whenever I am using feign or rest template for internal calls other ms throws 401. So my requirement will be to implement my microservices such that all the communication can be done between ms and external communication can be done using api gateway.

Comment: Also dicussed here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/146154/securing-micro-services-architecture-internally

Answer (score 6):

It all depends on what are the exact requirements of your project.

Gateway API usually is used to hide the complexity of microservice from external users that usually have 1 endpoint to talk to.

Also the gateway can handle the security and Authenticate the user (which many companies do indeed).

Now when you pass the gateway and your authenticated request reaches the client, usually you already have a user identity on the request (what was put onto the request by the gateway).

So you know that user "John Smith" has triggered the request.

And now if you need to call another microservice you should decide (and again its your decision):

1. Whether you need an authentication at all there (maybe internal communication doesn't have to be secured between microservices(
2. If you do need an authentication between microservices, who authenticates the request?
   If its a gateway, all authentication logic is there, but you have to make an additional hop for each request that might be costy
   Alternatively If its a direct call, each microservice must implement an authenticat logic. Sure, there is stuff like spring security, other languages/ecosystem have similar solutions, but in general this can be difficult to implement.
3. If you do make an authenticated call from microservice A to microservice B and the flow was originated by user John Smith that triggered a request to service A, you should decide whether the semantics of the call is:

   - User "John Smith" contacts the service B, or...
   - Service A contacts Service B on behalf of user John Smith.
     This is really important for authorization if you have any kind of permissions system.
4. In term of technical implementation usually you can add a JWT header to the request with the required token. If the request was already authenticated and you need to generate user identity, you can merely put a couple of headers on the request.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But what is troubling me is how to make the internal communication without authentication if I am using api gateway for authentication of our ms.

Comment: Well, when micro-service A contacts micro-service B it doesn't necessarily passes the request through the gateway. It can contact it directly... In this case it won't use any authentication if service B doesn't have authentication checks itself

Comment: Doesn't it expose my api as I am leaving that api without authentication. Can you please explain what kind of infrastructure should I build to support all this. I am thinking of the following: 1:Create Zuul api gateway which will be responsible for all the authentication, logging, tracing etch 2: config server for the application related configurations. So if i go with this approach doesn't my micrsoservices will remains open and anyone can directly call my microservice api leaving the api gateway, how to make my microservices only exposed to the api gateway and other microservices.

Comment: Not sure I'm following. If you use "1" then all the auth is done in the gateway. Once you pass the gateway (initial request from the user) all subsequent requests to the microservices that are running behind the API do not require the authentication between them. Of course, they're not "exposed" to the end user, only the gateway is. You should setup the network infrastructure so that only the gateway will be exposed to the "outer world"

Comment: Also I am thinking of using the service mesh(kiali for all the inter service communication) but I am not able to find any related project or code for the same. If possible you can provide with me the sample microservice project which can solve all my problems and which build according to the enterprise level application.

Comment: Well it really depends - you can use spring boot + spring security for security. Some kind of gateway (here you can go with java solutions, like Zuul or reactor, or use things like nginx). Service Mesh will shine if you have heterogenous environment (python, node, java microservices and so forth). So there are many options

Answer (score 0):

You can have two api gateway:

- one exposed outside
- and another one for microservices communication within container.

The one which is exposed outside does the validation of tokens and send claims to the microservices where those claims are used for validation of route protection.

Between microservices communication, send claims that you already have with the second gateway. Hope this helps. If you have found any alternative way let us know.